# Getting org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.BadExitStatusException: Command returned exit status 1: in Jenkins pipeline execution

Tags: jenkins, groovy

sshCommand remote: remote, command: "activationkey=$(cat testFile.sh | grep ACTIVATION_KEY | awk  -v FS="(ACTIVATION_KEY=)" '{print $2}')", sudo: "true"

This throws the error in Jenkins pipeline execution.
org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.BadExitStatusException: Command returned exit status 1: sudo -S -p 'c72671a0-9c6e-4e35-97a3-f63746cda98b'

Comment: I'm getting the same error message for the following command: sshCommand remote: remote, command: "/bin/rootsh -i -u ccdokr0", sudo: true. I'm trying to switch to a different user. The error message does not really provide much help!